# instantiating an inner abstract class of another abstract class

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class, inner-classes

I have an abstract class that has another inner abstract class like following:

```
public abstract class TemplateFace {

    public abstract Layout generateFace();

    public abstract class PopulateGridHandler implements ClickHandler {

        @Override
        public abstract void onClick(ClickEvent event);
    }
}
```

And I have another class which extends this **TemplateFace** class as the following:

```
public class AdminFace extends TemplateFace {
    private ListGrid adminListGrid;

    public Layout generateFace() {
        adminListGrid = GridBuilder.buildFullGrid(this);
    }

    public class PopulateGridHandler implements ClickHandler {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // some implementations...
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally I am trying to use the inner PopulateGridHandler class of the  AdminFace class (the class that extended the abstract one) inside another class like the following:

```
public class GridBuilder {

    // Here i get the argument as abstract class
    public static ListGrid buildFullGrid(TemplateFace templateFace)
    {
        ToolStripButton addRowButton = new ToolStripButton();
        addRowButton.setPrompt("Add new record");

        // I get the error here saying: Cannot instantiate the type 
        // TemplateFace.PopulateGridHandler
        addRowButton.addClickHandler(  templateFace.new PopulateGridHandler() );
    }
}
```

**ALL IN ALL**, I am just trying to utilize an abstract class which has another abstract class in it. However the java compiler thinks that I am trying to instantiate an abstract class. How can I workaround the problem?

Thanks for  any help, recommendation, comments...

Comment: Try this ((AdminFace)templateFace).new PopulateGridHandler()

Comment: @TAsk yes :) But thats not my intention. I am trying to trigger the onClick() method of PopulateGridHandler from GridBuilder class. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @alkis It does not solve my need. Because casting to AdminFace is killing my abstraction.(which means I cannot use this feature for example EndUserFace class). Therefore I dont want to mention any casting

Comment: Then you should implement it in a base class. The compiler can't know that you will never put an argument the abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler only knows about the declared type of your parameter `templateFace` that is - in this case - `TemplateFace`. So the expression

```
templateFace.new PopulateGridHandler()
```

does exactly mean that: Instantiate the *abstract* class `PopulateGridHandler` (which isn't allowed).

Actually it seems that you tried to override an inner abstract class definition in a subclass. That won't work. Only methods can be overridden. And this is also the way to go:

```
public abstract class TemplateFace {
    public abstract Layout generateFace();
    public abstract PopulateGridHandler createPopulateGridHandler();
    protected abstract class PopulateGridHandler implements ClickHandler{
        @Override
        public abstract void onClick(ClickEvent event); 
    }
}
```

Then declare your subclass as following:

```
public class AdminFace extends TemplateFace{
    private ListGrid adminListGrid;
    public Layout generateFace() {
        adminListGrid = GridBuilder.buildFullGrid(this);       
    }
    public PopulateGridHandler createPopulateGridHandler() {
        return new MyPopulateGridHandler();
    }
    private class MyPopulateGridHandler extends PopulateGridHandler {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { // some implementations ... }
    }
}
```

And then simply use the method `createPopulateGridHandler` for creating such a class:

```
public static ListGrid buildFullGrid(TemplateFace templateFace) {
    ToolStripButton addRowButton = new ToolStripButton();
    addRowButton.setPrompt("Add new record");
    addRowButton.addClickHandler(templateFace.createPopulateGridHandler());
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That was really what I was trying to solve. Thanks so much.